# Pyqt4 QFileDialog Constructor: what to use as parent parameter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm using pyqt4 and python 2.7.11.  I have a problem with the file/directory dialogs: I don't know what to use as the parent parameter.

If I use "self" or "None", PyCharm tells me that it's expecting "QFileDialog", and it got "AppTest" and "None" instead, respectively.

If I use "parent=self" or "parent=None", PyCharm tells me that the "self" parameter is unfilled.

Please see the example code below; I'm using Qt Designer to create the ui, let me know if you need that code as well.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import ui_test as main_frame


class AppTest(QtGui.QMainWindow, main_frame.Ui_MainAppWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(AppTest, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton1.clicked.connect(self.dialog1)
        self.show()

    def dialog1(self):
        file1 = str(QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
                parent=self,
                caption="Locate file 1",
                directory="",
                filter="Graphics files (*.jpg *.jpeg)"))

        print file1


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = AppTest()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

EDIT: Here's the code for the ui:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'test_ui.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainAppWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainAppWindow):
        MainAppWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainAppWindow"))
        MainAppWindow.resize(269, 195)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainAppWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.pushButton1 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton1.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton1.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton1"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton1)
        self.pushButton2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton2"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton2)
        MainAppWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainAppWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainAppWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainAppWindow):
        MainAppWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainAppWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton1.setText(_translate("MainAppWindow", "PushButton1", None))
        self.pushButton2.setText(_translate("MainAppWindow", "PushButton2", None))
```

Comment: yes please post the code of the `main_frame`

Comment: I've added the code for the main_frame (there's a second button that is not used in the example code)

Comment: i believe you mean the `parent` parameter not `self` i've tested on python3 and python2 but i don't see any warnings. Moreover if you're bordered about the error you can set parent to `None` that's the default value anyway so you don't even need to set it since you have only one window at the moment

Comment: @danidee Indeed I meant the `parent` parameter, thanks for clearing up that confusion, I've edited my question. I've added more details; I've tried using `None` but I get the same type of error...This bothers me because although the app runs, I'm having issues where the default directory is not the last one used but the one where the executable for the app is located; I'm wondering if the issue I'm describing could have something to do with that.

Comment: that's because you didn't specify the directory you just passed in an empty string set it to something like this `directory="/home/simonthechain"`

Comment: @danidee As I understand it, if the directory isn't specified, it should use the system's last directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110766/discussion-between-danidee-and-simon-thechain).